# R code analyze csv file larger than 8GB

Tags: r

My dataset is an csv file bigger than 8GB. I have a few lines of code filter it to make it smaller. Since the file is too big, no way to run r code. Error message pop out as no enough memory. My R studio is 64 bit version on Windows. Any expert know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to buy more memory, you should adapt your algorithm to process the file smaller blocks (e.g., first rows 1-10000, then rows 10001-20000 etc.) Also using the `data.table` package may help to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what oseiskar said, you could try `sqldf` package to pre-process the data in a small SQL database and query only what your computer can handle. There's also a [high performance task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) that deals with large data sets and out of memory processing.

Answer (score 0):

Package `bigmemory` might be an answer for your needs

Link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/vignettes/Overview.pdf